# php - how to check if there is text within XML element

Tags: php, xml

:) Let's say that i have that code:

```
<sample number="1">TEXT</sample>
```

but sometimes it could be

```
<sample number"1"/>
```

Q: How to check if it's self closed or not ? Or I want to check if it's there TEXT within element `sample`

Note: I'm using that way to retrieve XML doc:

```
$content = @file_get_contents($url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
```

Comment: Why is it important to know exactly how the user wrote the syntax?  Would you want to reject `<sample number="1"></sample>`?

Comment: This is not an answer, but... it's usually wrong to want to detect this, for pedantic semantic reasons. Just parse the XML in whatever [valid] form it comes, deal with the data, and move on.

Comment: No, I want to reject `<sample number"1"/>`. and retrieve data from `<sample number="1">sample</sample>`

Comment: I ask because, that data contain link to IMG,and when it's self closed -> no IMG, site looks ugly. I want to handle this.

Comment: @CappY: So you just want to determine if there is text within the element?

Comment: @CappY: You might want to edit your question to say that (test whether there is text and/or sub-elements within an element).  That is probably a much easier question, and makes more sense to do than what you are asking now.

Comment: @Jeremiah: for subelements im checking with isset($xml->element->subelement), that don't work with text within sub-element. And either == NULL

Answer (score 2):

You need to type cast the element to string, then check if it's empty or not.
Here's a quick example:

```
$test = simplexml_load_string("<test><elem test='12'><sub /><sub /></elem><elem test='12'>hi</elem><elem test='9' /><elem /></test>");
foreach($test as $elem){

    echo "\n";
    var_dump($elem);
    if((string)$elem == '' && $elem->count() == 0)
        echo 'Empty';
    else
        echo 'Full';


}
```

Will return:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["test"]=>
    string(2) "12"
  }
  ["sub"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (0) {
    }
  }
}
Full
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["test"]=>
    string(2) "12"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(2) "hi"
}
Full
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["test"]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
}
Empty
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (0) {
}
Empty
```

Comment: That wasn't so clean solution for me, and after 1hour spending in searching cleaner solution i found that way works: 

`if((string) $xml->sample != NULL)`

But thanks for answering. :)

Comment: I don't see how this might be cleaner. You're typecasting something to a string, and then compare it to something that is not a string. As you make a != and not a !==. php 'convert' the NULL to "". So basically, you're doing the same thing as me, except that you just check if their's text content, and not if their's child-elements.

Comment: @FMaz008's answer is perfectly fine for me, I don't see what's so unclear about it. In addition, your suggestion (string-casting and then comparing to `null`) doesn't make any sense and is misleading since string-casting will never result in `null`.